# Mapping a single navigation property in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am working on a project which involves EF Core.

I would like to use the foreign keys from `Category` with one single navigation property.

Therefore, `Item` stores the foreign keys of `Category`, and the names of the `Category` can be shown.

This is how the relationship looks like:

[image: Relationship]

Classes:

```
[Table("Item" , Schema = "public")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ItemID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CategoryID {get; set;}
    //Single Navigation Property
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}

[Table("Category" , Schema = "public")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Category");
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasOne(i=>i.Category)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Item>(i=>i.CategoryID);
}
```

It shows an error

> Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "IX_ItemDB_CategoryID"

Apparently, it means `CategoryID` cannot be duplicate in `Item`.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: `.WithOne()` must be `.WithMany()`, that's it. Also you don't need fluent configuration at all since the relationship, navigation property(es), FK, cascade delete behavior for such model (following EF Core naming conventions) is implied automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ivan Stoev` is correct. The model of my question is fine and fluent configurations are not required. EFCore will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

actually your answer in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1). What you need to do is change the location of the navigation property. So **Item** should not have an **Category** property, **Category** should have a **collection of Item** for single navigation. the article describes other ways.

Answer (score 0):

In case I understand properly You need `one to many` relation and I can offer you that structure and if you use Migration your tables will be properly build in the database. No to do anything in the FluentApi to, Your FK, PK(identity) and Indexes will be automatically created

```
[Table("Item" , Schema = "public")]
public class Item
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public Category Category {get; set;}
}

[Table("Category" , Schema = "public")]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
       this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items {get; set;}
}
```